# Do Tatara and Hanaoka end up together?

Tags: welcome-to-the-ballroom

I watched the anime because on MAL its written that the anime is romance drama.. Etc. The thing is Tatara seems to like Hanaoka so, is the romance between them? Because I like a romance which starts to grow from the beginning. Not in the mid a new character comes and ruin things up.

To be precise I want to know if Tatara and Hanaoka will end up together or not so I know I should watch and read ballroom e youkoso

And I don't care about the spoilers so feel free to say what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Since the manga isn't over, nothing's set in stone, yet. So, I can only give you my assumptions.

I'm actually quite sure that there is or will never be a romantic vibe between Tatara and Shizuku. As *Prasanth* has already said, Tatara probably never held any romantic feelings for her, but rather admiration and respect.

Moreover, the main heroine actually is Chinatsu and not Shizuku as many might have assumed while watching the first half of the anime. Chinatsu appears in the second half and henceforth always stays in the foreground with Tatara as his main dance partner (Shizuku and Mako were only temporary ones). She simply didn't show up at the very beginning of the story. That's why I'm very confident to say that the romance tag refers to the relationship between Tatara and Chinatsu.

The story focuses mainly on the character development of and the relationship btw. these two protagonists. *"After a difficult start because of their completely different personalities and background, Chinatsu and Tatara slowly find themselves on the same wavelength and steadily grow together as dance partners and reach new heights."* That's probably a suitable synopsis of their relationship.

Btw., there has been quite a few hints in the anime that this relationship is slowly progressing in a romantic way. So, if you want to ship Tatara with Shizuku, then you'll most likely be disappointed (Shizuku's romantic relationship also probably revolves around her main dance partner Kiyoharu).

I personally am more than satisfied with the relationship btw. our two protagonists and I really want to encourage you not to give up watching this anime only because you initially shipped Tatara with Shizuku. I'm quite sure that you will change your mind as the story progresses.

Answer (score 0):

There are some scenes where Tatara feels attracted towards Hanaoka, but I think not in romance-kind of attraction, but kind of respect for her in the dance field, a similar thing which Mako had for Tatara.

Maybe this will end up like you said, in romance.

Answer (score 0):

In Manga, Tatara And Shizuka are dancing in all England dance championship. So I'm not dropping the the idea of their romantic development. Chinatsu is more progressed in story. But romantic connection is zero. Tatara only cares to share the stage with Shizuka. Manga have more moments between them which were romantic instead just inspiration. Chinatsu still in friend zone.